# How can I open my React native app Dockerized?

Tags: react-native, docker, dockerfile, expo

I am having some issues to dockerize my react native app, I can create the image correctly but, I do not know how to open it in both devices, my own mobile and emulator one.

This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:16
ARG NODE_ENV=production
ENV NODE_ENV $NODE_ENV
ARG PORT=19006
ENV PORT $PORT
EXPOSE $PORT 19001 19002
ENV NPM_CONFIG_PREFIX=/home/node/.npm-global
ENV PATH /home/node/.npm-global/bin:$PATH
RUN npm install -g expo-cli@latest
RUN yarn global add @expo/ngrok@4.1.0
RUN mkdir /opt/react_native_app
WORKDIR /opt/react_native_app
ENV PATH /opt/react_native_app/.bin:$PATH
COPY ./package.json ./package-lock.json ./
RUN npm install
WORKDIR /opt/react_native_app/app
COPY . .
CMD ["npx", "expo", "start", "--non-interactive"]
```

This is how I run the image:

```
docker run -p 19006:19006 -p 19001:19001 -p 19002:19002 mobile
```

And this is what terminal says:

```
Starting project at /opt/react_native_app/app
Starting Metro Bundler
Waiting on http://localhost:8081
Logs for your project will appear below.
```

How can I watch my app on my phone and the emulator? My ip is: 192.168.0.15

**UPDATE**

I have managed to display the following (I know images are not good, but this is too long)

[image]

Of course I have Xcode updated and I can run my app with the command `npx expo start` and select 'i' option to open it on the iphone emulator.

Does anyone know this error?

Comment: If the application is publishing port 8081, that needs to be the second port number in a `docker run -p` option.

Comment: Hi, sorry but I do not understand what do you mean, could you please give more an example?